# Class not found error but class is available

Tags: php, oop

I have my folder structure like

1) samples folder contains all the requested file

2) lib folder contains all the required classes

When i am running a particular file `RequestPermissionsReceipt.php` file it is showing error that

> Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope' not found in
>   samples/RequestPermissionsReceipt.php on line 59

but this class is available in the `lib\PayPal\Types\Common` folder.

What should i do to remove this error ? Code of my `RequestPermissionsReceipt` file is

```
use PayPal\Service\PermissionsService;
use PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope;
use PayPal\Types\Perm\RequestPermissionsRequest;

require_once('PPBootStrap.php');

$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$serverPort = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
$url =  dirname('http://'.$serverName.':'.$serverPort.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$returnURL = $url."/GetAccessToken.php";
$cancelURL = $url. "/RequestPermissions.php";

$scope = array();
   if(isset($_POST['chkScope'])) {
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($_POST['chkScope'] as $value) {
          $scope[$i++] = $value;
      }
   }
$requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
```

Comment: Can you show us your `RequestEnvelope` file? Does the file have the correct namespace?

Comment: My RequestEnvelope file is located in lib/PayPal/Types/Common folder and has this namespace in there "namespace PayPal\Types\Common;"

Comment: Are you autoloading from `lib` or something?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No i am not autoloading from lib or something

Comment: In these three lines what have i to change, so that it started working use PayPal\Service\PermissionsService;
use PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope;
use PayPal\Types\Perm\RequestPermissionsRequest;

Comment: I have two folder 1) lib, in lib there is PayPal folder and in PayPal folder there is other folders which are used in these three lines. 2)Samples folder which contains RequestPermissionsReceipt.php file